# Diamond Drawing in Console

Tags: java, console

I have been working on a problem for a few days now to draw a diamond inside of the console that asks for user input, and then draws the diamond in respect to the size that was inputed.

I can't draw the diamond in here because the formatting doesn't show up correctly.

I have been able to successfully get the top half of the diamond to work, and I thought the bottom half would be easy as it would just be the reverse of the top, however I'm stuck on something and I cant seem to figure it out.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Diamond {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // import the scanner
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Ask for the number of sides
        System.out.println("Enter the diamond size: ");
        int sides = scanner.nextInt();

        //variables for the diamond
        int matrix = sides * 2 + 3;
        int midpoint = ((matrix - 1) / 2) + 1;
        int mspaces = 0;
        int centerSpaces = 0;


        // diamond gets made here
        for (int rows = 1; rows <= midpoint; rows++) {
            int spaces = (sides * 2 + 2) - (sides + rows);
            if (rows == 1) {
                for (int x = 1; x <= spaces; x++) {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
                System.out.print("^\n");
            }

            //top half of the diamond
            if (rows > 1 && rows < midpoint) {

                if (rows > 2) {
                    mspaces += 2;
                }

                for (int x = 1; x <= spaces; x++) {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
                System.out.print("/");

                for (int k = 0; k <= mspaces; k++) {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }

                System.out.print("\\\n");

                centerSpaces = mspaces + 2;

            }

            //center of the diamond
            if (rows == midpoint) {
                System.out.print("<");
                for (int i = 0; i <= centerSpaces; i++) {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
                System.out.print(">");
            }
        }

        //Bottom half of the diamond
        for (int x = midpoint - 1; x <= 1; x--) {

            int downSpace = (sides * 2 + 2) - (sides + x);

            System.out.println("\n");

            if (x == 1) {
                for (int y = 1; y <= downSpace; y++) {
                    System.out.println(" ");
                }

                if (x > 2) {
                    mspaces += 2;
                }

                for (int y = 1; x <= downSpace; y++) {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
                System.out.print("\\");

                for (int k = 0; k <= mspaces; k++) {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }

                System.out.print("/\n");

                centerSpaces = mspaces + 2;

            }
        }

    }
}
```

If I had to take a guess on what it is, it would be something in the `if` statement for the bottom half of the diamond, but I'm not exactly sure.

EDIT:

Here is a screenshot of the top half of the diamond:

[image]

Comment: Can you paste what the incorrect result looks like?

Comment: @turbo I've added a screenshot of the top half, the problem right now is nothing in the bottom half is printing out...

Comment: Rather than post screen-shots, it would be better to post the actual output.  Do you know how to copy text from the command line?  What OS do you use?

Comment: @AndrewThompson I'm using OSX 10.9.1, Mavericks I think ? Programming in Eclipse...

Comment: While I could tell you how to copy text from the Windows command line, I am not familiar with OS X.

Comment: @AndrewThompson still not sure what you mean by copying text from the command line, maybe its something I can look up

Comment: command line == console

Comment: @AndrewThompson ahh makes, sense now... :) I think I've got enough of a boost to be able to figure it out from here! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop never runs: should read `x>=1` (i think)

```
for (int x = midpoint - 1; x <= 1; x--)
```

Possible infinite loop: should read `y <= downSpace`

```
for (int y = 1; x <= downSpace; y++)
```

Comment: There are more bugs than just these two.  For example, there's a `System.out.println(" ");` that should be `System.out.print`.  There are others.  The OP just needs to go through and deal with these little things one by one.

Comment: @DavidWallace fixed all of the ones you noted, as well as everyone elses, somethings still off, but at least i got something to happen for the bottom part

Comment: Yes, I know there are others.  I found the same two as ns47731 initially.  I'm not going to spend my time investigating and typing up what all the problems are.  But I think you can now see enough of the diamond to be able to work it out for yourself.  You'll just have to be persistent.

Comment: @DavidWallace Thanks for the help, I'll definitely be able to get it from here on out... I was just looking for a bit of a boost to get past the bottom issue.